# How can I toggle position of listview on button click

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-relativelayout

I have a list view with initially place above the button, but on clicking of the button I want button to be placed on top of listview. Below is the xml. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/parentView"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/likes_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:padding="20dp" />       

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/comments_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:padding="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/like_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/likes_list"
        android:text="Likes"
        android:onClick="onClickLikeButton"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/comment_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/likes_list"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/like_button"
        android:text="Comments" 
        android:onClick="onClickCommentButton" />
```

Comment: you can set two button initialy one above the list and one below the list.and set visibility gone for above one but on click list item set visibility view and gone for below one button.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, use findViewById and get Button. Then, set LayoutParams as following:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) button2.getLayoutParams();
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.listViewId);
button2.setLayoutParams(rlp);
```